# a strange json format

Tags: json, reactjs

Can someone help me with the following JSON format.

```
deals: {
        'obj-1': { id: '1', name: 'a', text: 'text' },
        'obj-2': { id: '2', name: 'b', text: 'text' }
    }
```

I'm doing a tutorial step by step and found this type of JSON, but I have doubts on how to reproduce it.

[JSON](https://github.com/rajatk16/infinity-war/blob/master/src/Data/index.js)

I understood that it is an object with several other objects.

bringing from my backend this would seriously list objects like that.

```
{
  "deals": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "a",
      "text": "text"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "b",
      "text": "text"
    }
  ]
}
```

starting now with react and I'm trying to understand a lot.

can someone help me to reproduce in this way or even explain a little more about this model?

create an object with several objects and name each one!

QUESTION: how to convert from the format that my backend returns me to that different format?

Comment: What is your question? Do you to convert from the first format to the second one, or the other way around?

Comment: how to convert from the format that my backend returns me to that different format?

Comment: what's "strange" here? The first block of code isn't JSON, it's literally just a fragment of JS object code.

Comment: you answered my first question, it is not a JSON.

Comment: I also answered the rest: you're showing a fragment of plain JS. add a `{` in front and a `}` at the end, and now it's regular JS code that you can load in like any other. The file you link to is _literally a javascript file_, it's not JSON. The one thing that might confuse you is that it's a more modern [javascript module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules). You import those directly using the `import` keyword, and you load them on a page with `type="module"` - they're not some data format you need to parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using forEach on `backend.deals`, you can extract each of the deals and assign it to `data` as an object:

```
const data = { deals: {}};
backend.deals.forEach(deal => { data.deals[`obj-${deal.id}`] = deal });
console.log(data);
```